# Heroku: deploying a JS web app containing a python package/venv

Tags: javascript, python, heroku, virtualenv

I made a web app made using react/node/postgresql. In this app, I'm using a js package called [*`python-bridge`*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-bridge) which lets me run python code within a js file. This is so that I can use a python package which doesn't have a good js alternative. Below is a simple example of python-bridge and python code in a js file:

```
'use strict';
 
let assert = require('assert');
let pythonBridge = require('python-bridge');
 
let python = pythonBridge();
 
python.ex`import math`;
python`math.sqrt(9)`.then(x => assert.equal(x, 3));
 
let list = [3, 4, 2, 1];
python`sorted(${list})`.then(x => assert.deepEqual(x, list.sort()));
 
python.end();
```

I created a venv with `$ python3 -m venv root/server` in order for this file to run the python package, which worked perfectly while developing and running locally on my machine using `$ source server/venv/bin/activate` then `$ yarn dev`.

I'm trying to deploy the app to Heroku, but the python code is not running. When checking the logs, I get the same error as I did when running my app locally without activating the venv. Below, 'recipe_scrapers' is the python package which imports a scraper function, and 'scraper' is the python variable that I assign to the function.

[image]

How can I deploy to Heroku so that the python code will run properly?

I have `requirements.txt` with all of the python dependencies and `runtime.txt` with `python-3.10.6` in my root. I tried adding the venv command to `Procfile` which didn't work (and feels like bad practice).

I'm not familiar with python, so apologies if I'm misunderstanding venvs/app deployment. Deploying a python app vs js app are the same from what I can tell, so I'm not sure what to change to get the app running properly on Heroku.

Comment: What is `python-bridge`? Can you link to something that explains what it is? -- Try to be more explicit about what you did in general... For example how did you create the Pyhton virtual environment?

Comment: @sinoroc https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-bridge

Comment: Edit your question to show the error messages.

Comment: @sinoroc I added a screenshot of the error messages. I mentioned in the OP but I get the same errors if I run the app locally without first activating venv. This makes me think that Heroku isn't installing the dependencies I have in my requrements.txt, but I don't know how to debug from here

Comment: Advice for next time: here on StackOverflow (and other similar websites as well) it is very much recommended against posting screenshots of code, error messages, or any kind of text in general. One should copy-paste instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue while poking around my Heroku settings. Turns out I needed to add python to the Buildpacks settings. So now I have both nodejs and python buildpacks, and the dependencies are installed when deploying (`python app detected... installing requirements with pip`).

tbh I didn't know about buildpacks before and didn't come across them while researching this issue, but I'm glad this was a simple fix in the end.